# Typing < and > characters with ANSI keyboard with a Hungarian QWERTZ layout

Tags: keyboard

Many keyboard layouts in Europe are based on the ISO keyboard layout which looks like this.

[image: 1]

In my language the <, > are located on the key next to left shift like this:

[image: 2]

There is a less/greater than on í and Y next to left shift!

The problem is that I am using an keyboard with ANSI mechanical layout. The ANSI mechanical layout does not have one of the keys

[image: 3]

Is there any way to enter less than < and greater than > characters on this ANSI keyboard using a Hungarian QWERTZ layout? Maybe through an AltGr combination?

Comment: Usually, the characters left of `Z` on an ISO keyboard move up to be left of `1` on an ANSI. Because you have the `Z/Y` swap for QWERTZ, I'd Expect `>` to still be on `Shift/Y`. I have no way to test this though, so can't add as an answer for now. idk what OS you're on but both Win & Mac have an onscreen keyboard you can quickly test with.

Comment: Yes, but i can type > just fine, because i have the button. i can't type the other one wich is this: <, but for that i have to switch to an english layout and back, and its really annoying

Comment: Did you try the key next to `1`? You can't just magic up a new key, ANSI has one physical key fewer than ISO… & that's the one missing, left of `z`.

Comment: It doesn't work :c

Comment: You're not really offering up much in the way of clarifications here. I guess we'll have to wait for someone Hungarian with an ANSI keyboard to come along.

Comment: Hi guys, i found a solution a long time ago, i just forgot to post it D: - I use this [ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/ ] free software by Microsoft called Power Toys, and you can rebind buttons with it, and add shortcut. I binded this [ < ] character to RightAlt + A and it works perfectly. I'm sure there are better ways to this but this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use right alt and m for "<" and right alt plus . for ">". Even tho I'm on ISO layout, I think it should work for ANSI as well.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot about this post, but I received an answer that led me back here. Not long after this question, I found Powertoys which is a great open source tool developed by Microsoft. It has a lot of cool features.

The important one for this question is keyboard manager (or at least I think that's what it's called, if not, something similar). It let's you rebind keys, edit and add new keybinds, which is how I solved my problem. I added a keybind, so when I press right alt + a, the '<' symbol will write, since that's the one I can't write because of the layout of my keyboard. So that's basically it, I hope this helps anyone that has the same question currently.